# Anchor Tag links are scrolling down too far but ONLY on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, anchor

I'm redesigning my portfolio site and I have a static bar fixed to the top of the site. Each link in the bar is an anchor link that scrolls down to it's corresponding ID. If you view the site in full screen mode the anchor links scroll exactly to where they are supposed to go, however if you resize the screen to the mobile view they end up scrolling down too far.

I suspect it has something to do with the piece of javascript below and the 45 offset. Problem is if a remove the offset it then scrolls down too far on both mobile and desktop.

```
<script>
 $('a[href*=#]').click(function(event){
 $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top - 45
    }, 500);
event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Any idea what could be causing this? It's been driving me crazy. Here is the [URL](http://ericfranklin.net/2014/) to the site.

Please try to ignore all the place holder text and images, I just started last night so it's far from being complete.

Comment: This is a design pattern that is used to often these days but you should investigate this one (link at the end) and see what they are doing and you're not. Your navigation is not static, it's fixed when scrolling static when it's toggled. The difference in location appears to be the height that the content is pushed down from the expanded menu. http://startbootstrap.com/templates/freelancer/

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had was on mobile we have a responsive menu which the user click to expand. When they clicked the link the page scrolls to the anchored link but overshot it.

Turns out the issue was that after they clicked the link the menu that had expanded to show the navigation was in-line and pushed the content down. Upon clicking a link the menu was setup to close again so the content shifted up.

The scroll action was going to the original position of the content at the time the menu was open.

Solutions are:

- Make the menu not push the content down but rather sit on top of the
  content
- Update the JS to offset the scroll by the height of the expanded menu
- Update the JS to close the menu before scrolling to the anchor